# Appending one sql query with another

Tags: sql, mysql, union

I have a datareader that binds a sql select (with 10 columns from table1) , i want to append another with 5 different cols from table2 to this first sql select, i can't do UNION as it has different number of columns, (one query has 10, another returns 5 cols).

Is there any other way of implementing this, via mysql?

Also i need to append the additional 5 columns based on a condition, is there via mysql select query to write with using if then in the select query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about unioning with nulls?  The query below will remove duplicates between the two datasets.

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1,col2,null,null
FROM table2
```

If you want to remove duplicates inside of each dataset use the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,col3,col4
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,null,null
FROM table2
```

You can use anything you want for the default value after col1 and col2.

null, 'none', '' all should work.

Comment: Remember that you probably want UNION ALL though, not UNION

Comment: Wouldn't the results be the same because of the nulls in the second query?

Comment: Thanks Abe, is there any way to remove the duplicate and show the entry value without null?

Comment: You can remove duplicates between the two datasets by using UNION ALL instead of UNION.  What do you mean by "show the entry value without null"?  I've updated the query to use UNION ALL

Comment: I have this condition in mysql query

SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM table1 -> this I select produces 5

 rows (R1,R2,R3,R4,R5) where (C1,c2,c3 are null) UNION SELECT 

col1,col2,null,null FROM table2; -> this II select produces 2 rows (R4,R5) where (C1,c2,c3 are not null)

Is there any way to remove the duplicate and show the entry value without null?

I want to send the query result with total of 5 rows with values for last 2 rows instead of total 7 rows.

Comment: Ok i got the answer on I select i added a not exists which checks data not in another table, then i combine with the II table.

SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4
FROM table1 and NOT EXISTS (select <primary_key_col> from table3 where table1.ID=table3.ID)
UNION 
SELECT col1,col2,null,null
FROM table2

Thanks.